# regular expression except some letters and some digits

Tags: regex, if-statement, awk

I have to find a word that does't start with "u" or "U" and it followed with 6 digits but it's doesn't work, this is what I'm trying:

```
if ($++I=='/^[^uU]+\d{6}/') print "I found it";
```

this is the sample of the entrance that ++I is giving
match:
s777777
t666666
doesn't match:
u666666
u55555
username
s77777
s7777777
s555555;
s777777uuij

this is inside of a awk the complete code:

```
awk '{
    if (/GRANT/||/REVOKE/) 
        if (/EXECUTE/||/REFERENCES/||/TRIGGER/||/ALL PRIVILEGES/) 
            print "ERROR";
        else{
            I=0;
            while (I<=NF){
                if ($I == "TO")
                    if ($++I ~ /^[^uU]+\d{6}/) 
                        print "se encontro";  
                    else    
                        print "no se encontro"
                I++
            }
        }
    }' file.txt
```

I keep trying and I came with this regex, but it still doesn't work when I put it in the awk I don't know why

```
^[^uU]\d{6}$[^;]
```

Comment: The `+` says one or more non-`u` character. Remove that, or change it to a `?` to make the `u`s optional. Also don't work with bash but `\d` may need to be `[0-9]`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: this is not proper `awk`, what are you trying to achieve? Is a 7 digit number valid?

Comment: no, 7 digits is not valid either 5 digits are valid either thanks for asking, I changed the hashtag

Comment: When you have time, you may wish to read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on formatting code on SO and the SO [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: There are a couple ambiguities in the question. Firstly, you don't say the "word" starts at the beginning of the string, but you do have a beginning-of-string anchor (^) in your regex. If you want to match `'U123456'` in `'Submarine U123456 is missing'`, you don't want the anchor. In any event you need to edit your question to clarify that point. Secondly while you say in a comment there must be exactly 6 digits following the u, you need put that in your question by editing. Questions should be self-contained, in part because not all readers read all comments.

Comment: Any success with the proposed approach?

Comment: I say word, and not sentence because it's an only word that I put examples after I really don't understand your comment  @CarySwoveland

Comment: You say you need to "find" a string that begins with `u` or `U` and is followed by 6 digits suggests that you want to know if such a string appears in a given (longer) string. By starting your regex with `^` means it must begin at the beginning of the longer string. For example suppose you are given a string `s = "abc u123456 def"`. The regex `/[uU]\d{6}/` will match `u123456` in `s` but `/^[uU]\d{6}/` will not, because `u123456` is not at the beginning of `s`

Comment: the example of the string that I will get is in the original post, I really don't understand why are you inventing sentences, I will not get a string like that

Comment: @CarySwoveland You misread part of the question. OP doesn't want the first character to be a `u`.

Comment: @Gabriela It would improve the question if you edit the question to show three examples that should match, and three that should fail. Reasons for the failures also may help if it is not clear.

Comment: there is with the examples to clarify thanks for the recommendation

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the first character cannot be `u` or `U`, but that is unrelated to the point I was trying to make about the anchor `^`.

Answer (score 0):

this is the one that worked

```
^[^uU][0-9]{6}$
```